# Calling method in current Activity

Tags: android, methods, android-activity

I wanna know - how to call method from MAIN activity to CURRENT (opened, on screen, on top of stack) activity?.

For example main Activity is `ActivityA`, and I open ANOTHER ACTIVITY - it's `ActivityB` OR `ActivityC` or any other. In `ActivityA` is handler (or timer) and when something happened I want to call `methodInActiveMethod()` .

I found for example:

```
class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    public void myMethod() 
    {
        MyActivity.runMyMethod();
    }
}


class MyActivity extends Activity 
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public static void runMyMethod() 
    {
        //Run code...
    }
}
```

And it works properly, but I wonder how to send method like `anyActivityOnTop.runMyMethod()` ?

(PS: I would be grateful for answers with code)

Comment: If you mean to "borrow" the code of the method to operate in the context of your current activity, you can - somewhat shadily - do what you are doing.  But if you want to run the method in the context of it's own activity, you should use an `Intent` to switch to that activity, and add logic which will activate that code path depending on parameters of the Intent.

Comment: But instead of `specificActiviti.method()` I want use "UNIVERSAL" call like `anyActivityOnTop.method()` - and I ask HOW CAN I ACHIEVE THIS

Comment: The methods for uncooperatively determining the top activity are considered unreliable.  But if you are calling a method of one of your activities, you could have each possible activity's onResume() method update something shared to indicate that this is now the top activity.

Comment: but how about NON STATIC methods? I need to call non static method - how can I do this even if I know in which Activity it is?
(`ActivityA.method()` doesnt work :( )

Comment: Then you definitely need an instance of the activity.  But you really should be using an Intent.  And more generally, you should probably take more time to understand what activities are, as what you want to do seems like it is likely in conflict with that.

Comment: I used `onNewIntent()` - you wrote at the beginning about Intents - if you want, you can write short answear instead of comment and I accept it (cant vote up) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement a listener and call when you need it

Comment: I wonder how to implement it - I should send msg from 1st activity to another and in 2nd lister for it? Or by intents? (I need send "data" from main activity to another ALREADY OPENED activity)